# What is the term for the matrix multiplication $a^{\top}Xa$ and what are the properties of this pattern?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I know I learned this before but I am struggling to come up with the name of the pattern that goes $a^{\top}Xa$ and I am also curious about the properties and interpretations of such a multiplication.

For instance, in Gaussian processes the variance calculation is something like...

$$
\sigma = k(x_*, x_*) - k_*^{\top}(K + \sigma^2I)k_*
$$

so how can I interpret the last term to intuitively understand what it's meaning is?

Comment: Maybe this is a bit of a silly comment: But every matrix $X$ represents a bilinear map and $a^\top X a$ represents this bilinear map applied to $(a,a)$.

Comment: We call $a^\top X a$ the *quadratic form* given by (square) matrix $X$.

Comment: @d Is $K$ a covariance matrix in this context?

Comment: @BenGrossmann yes, in the example I gave, it is a covariance matrix, but my question was also applicable to the general case of seeing this pattern

Comment: @delta Well when the matrix $X$ is positive definite, the expression $a^TXa$ has a particularly "nice" interpretation, hence the question. In particular, if $X$ is positive definite, then $a^TXa$ describes a norm. You can think of it as a "weighted" version of the usual norm function $a^Ta$.